# Reveal entry's parents recursively, but not siblings

Tags: org-mode

I use sparse trees a lot.

A problem I have is that they show entries without context. For instance, with a tree like:

`* A
** AA
*** AAA    :tag2:
*** BBB    :tag1:`

if I run a sparse tree that matches BBB, it would show:

`* A
*** BBB    :tag1:`

(with BBB highlighted).

I know I can go to an entry and `C-c C-r` to reveal the context. That, however, shows siblings as well as parents, which can get really noisy.

I'd like to reveal the parents only, all the way to the top. For the previous example, what I mean is getting:

`* A
** AA
*** BBB    :tag1:`

Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the following works:

```
(push '(tags-tree . canonical) org-show-context-detail)
```